# Вывести полученные простые числа в <body> html

Tags: javascript, html

Ниже скрипт js, определяющий все простые числа от 2 до 500.

Необходимо вывести в  HTML все простые числа.

Как это сделать?

Вот js

```js
const CEILING = 500;

//Declare function

function primeTest(testValue) {
    let isPrime = true;
    for ( let i = 2; i<testValue; i++ ) {
        if ( testValue % i === 0 ) {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}

//Use function

for (let i = 2; i<=CEILING; i++) {
    let result = primeTest(i);
    if (result == false) {
      continue;
    }

    console.log(i + " is a prime number.");

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>An empty page</title>
    <script src="JS/primeScript.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Вместо `console.log(...);` добавьте вот это `document.body.innerHTML += i + '\n';`

Comment: Работает! Спасибо )